# MyComputer as initial directory

Tags: wpf, dialog

Is there a way for a open file dialog to use the "My Computer" instead of a specific path. In this example, the W: drive is the intial directory.

```
Dim dlgOpen As New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog

dlgOpen.Filter = "Bases de données Access(*.mdb)|*.mdb"
dlgOpen.InitialDirectory = "W:"
```

I figure there must be a value or function that return the My Computer path, but what is it?

Thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My Computer is a virtual folder. It has a predefined GUID. Here is how you get My Computer

```
 OpenFileDialog d = new OpenFileDialog();
 d.InitialDirectory = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}";
 d.ShowDialog();
```

If you want to know about special folders

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

but be aware of

> The MyComputer constant always yields
>   the empty string ("") because no path
>   is defined for the My Computer folder.

Comment: Wow... way to change something like 'My Computer' into something much much clearer :)

Comment: Alternatively you can try to use a [shell shortcut](https://ss64.com/nt/shell.html) for this: `d.InitialDirectory = "shell:MyComputerFolder";`

Answer (score 4):

A good way to handle this is using the "special folders" in the .NET Environment library.

For instance, the "My Documents" (personal) would use:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

Comment: I tried this but this doensn't seem to work out :
dlgOpen.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer)

Comment: Svetlozar Angelov is correct though... it looks like "My Computer" is actually undefined...

Comment: Guess my computer doesn't work because I get "" when I substitute Personal for MyComputer. I'll use Desktop instead.
Tks